# How to set the Origin for an Engineering Coordinate Reference System using Geotools?

Tags: java, gis, geotools

I am trying to code a transformation from a local 3D Cartesian (which is attached to a moving platform) to geocentric coordinate reference system (CRS) using the [referencing module](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/index.html) of [Geotools](https://geotools.org/). The [geotools user guide](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/crs.html) mentions a "A contextually local coordinate reference system (for construction projects or moving objects)", which sounds exactly like the CRS I need. However, the guide and documentation of Geotools is unclear on how to define the origin and orientation of such a CRS.

Geotools provides a [Constructor](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/referencing/crs/DefaultEngineeringCRS.html#DefaultEngineeringCRS-java.lang.String-org.opengis.referencing.datum.EngineeringDatum-org.opengis.referencing.cs.CoordinateSystem-) for creation of an EngineeringCRS, which requires a EngineeringDatum as a parameter. This Datum can be created using a [DatumFactory](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/opengis/referencing/datum/DatumFactory.html#createEngineeringDatum-java.util.Map-), however the method does not specify how to define the "AnchorPoint" of the CRS, which I assume is the origin.

I'd like to do something like this

```java
EngineeringDatum bodyFrameOrigin = new DefaultEngineeringDatum(/* specify name, origin, orientation,and baseCRS */)
EngineeringCRS bodyFrame = DefaultEngineeringCRS("bodyFrame", bodyFrameOrigin, DefaultCarthesianCS.GENERIC_3D);
```

I'd expect the call `bodyFrame.getDatum().getAnchorPoint()` to return a string describing the origin. Further I'd expect `CRS.getTransform(bodyFrame, WGS84_3D)` to return a valid coordinate transformation between the coordinate systems.